# Working on breadboard but not on PCB

Tags: mosfet

I want to check what's going wrong. The circuit controls fan speed, based on temperature, with an Arduino Nano.

First, I've created te following circuit:
[image: circuit drawing]

Gate resistor: 1K
Mosfet pulldown resistor: 47K

Then I noticed I actually created a voltage divider (R2 and R3) that's messing with the Mosfet's Gate.

So I tried to 'solve' it by "hacky" soldering (notice connection between R2 and R3):
[image: tried to solve voltage divider]

**Problem:** But the Mosfet doesn't behave like the on the breadboard.

More drawings of PCB;
PCB front:
[image: pcb front]
PCB bottom:
[image: pcb bottom]

I am not sure what's wrong:

- Did my "hacky" soldering not work out?
- Did the soldering break the MOSFET?
- Something else?

I assume the circuit drawing should be like this (revised): (but I don't know at this point)
[image]

Can someone help me getting on the right track? Is my assumption correct?

Comment: What does this circuit even do? Should it be some sort of switch for a fan? What are your resistor values?

Comment: Doesn't the FET blow up if it has to charge an absurd amount of 6000uF capacitance?

Comment: D1 is backwards.

Comment: The circuit controls fan speed, based on temperature, with an Arduino Nano. I've added some capacitors to smooth out the PWM.

Comment: @Justme especially since FET does not even have a heat sink.

Comment: Gate resistor:  1K
Mosfet pulldown resistor: 47K
On breadboard this works perfect, but on PCB not. Is it because my trick (notice connection between R2 and R3 on 2nd image) doesn't work like I expected?

Comment: No need for tricks. Choose a more suitable mosfet as you are only lucky if your current one works. The gate resistor should be closer to 22Ohms rather than 1k. The ‘discharge’ resistor can be a much higher value. Your method of fan speed control is rather crude. You can get fans with the control electronics already implemented - so called ‘4 wire’ fans used in PCs. All that is required is a pwm signal. No need for huge amounts of capacitance. Have you seen a commercial fan speed controller that uses your technique?

Comment: Rerouting your gate bias resistor like you did in your second schematic does not make much of a difference. You should add some series resistance to the load. Caps will draw current during connection of 12V due to reverse recovery of body diode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have it. D1 is correct on both drawings. D1 is not needed with the MOSFET you picked, it is an avalanche rated device.  On the second drawing try using a 50K for R3 and a 27 Ohm for R2. Even though it is a logic level device  it needs just shy of 9V Vgs to be fully  enhanced to achieve the lowest RDSon at temperature. At 4V Vgs it will switch over 50A. Looking at the SOA of the MOSFET and some rough assumptions of circuit impedance it should support that capacitance as the surge is a pulse. If you are using the PWM capability of pin 9, which I think you are, you need to lose the capacitors, maybe one small one to control noise.  From what I can see the soldering looks good. If you have a noise or control problem with the fan you need a different fan. I used the IR PD-94831 data sheet for a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I indeed use the PWM capability. If I understand you correct; could the MOSFET behave better/normal if I remove capacitors?

Comment: Definitely! I hope your power supply is at least 2A. I assumed that from the drawing.

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. Also, I've mitigated the noise by [lowering the Arduino PWM frequency](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency/) to 31 Hz. Thanks again for your helpful reply, I've learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, charging the capacitors with the MOSFET is pulling down the input voltage which is causing the Nano to reset.

The current is essentially unlimited- with the typical 5V drive from the ATMega the MOSFET will try to charge the capacitors with about 100A, so the 12V will get dropped across something.

Perhaps there was enough series resistance in your breadboard that it more-or-less worked. PWM into capacitors is not generally a good idea. If you must, add some series resistance or inductance to limit the current. If you add resistance it will dissipate power. If you add inductance you will need a flyback diode from the drain to +12. The present diode is doing nothing of value.

Comment: The amount of capacitors are definitely overkill, but I didn't realize it would hurt the working of the MOSFET. The Nano doesn't reset btw, so I might be lucky. This is my first time messing around with PCBs. Thanks for your comment.